# How to dump a user defined or system compiled function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, dump

Is there any way to dump a user defined or system compiled function same as `print_r` or `var_dump` for variables in PHP?

for example:

```
dump('echo');
```

or

```
dump('my_function');
```

Comment: What do you suppose to see?

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php perhaps?

Comment: `echo` is not function. But you can try to look for `ReflectionFunction` class. Should help, but not sure if that's what you want

Comment: `ReflectionFunction` doesn't help, I'm goint to trace function's code.

Comment: What is it in specific you are trying to do??

Comment: The benefit of doing this is some frameworks such as `Zend` extend some function to PHP global functions such as `zend_report_statistics` and I want to see their structures in my debug pages because they compiled in `dll` files.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to take a really convoluted route to debugging something!  You're far better off using an IDE with support for XDebug or PHPDBG that will let you single-step through the code, set breakpoints, etc.

Comment: So you want debugging. http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Even `debug_backtrace()` doesn't help. `debug_backtrace()` just trace recursive callbacks, not dump their structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a function would be powerful.

Some tools outside of PHP will help: A debugger, like gdb; a refactoring tool, like resharper/MonoDev and some tracing tools, like strace/dtrace. You would also use some tools, which expose internals, like [Derick's VLD](http://derickrethans.nl/more-source-analysis-with-vld.html) or [PVT](https://github.com/ax330d/pvt/tree/master/pvt), which can dump the opcodes to a readable format, from there, it's not totally impossible to (re)create the code from it.

Especially, in regard to commercial PHP extensions and products, like Zend Core/Platform or Zend Server it would be a reverse engineering / disassembling technique, because you are asking for C/C++ extension code from inside PHP.

You ain't gonna need this technique!

> The benefit of doing this is some frameworks such as Zend extend some
>   function to PHP global functions such as zend_report_statistics and I
>   want to see their structures in my debug pages because they compiled
>   in dll files.

There is no real benefit, except debugging, in seeing the interals of a little stats reporting function.

And by the way, the first thing you would see, when doing a `dump('echo');` is, that `echo` is a language construct and not a function.